# Cannot get token from email link using $_GET (php)

Tags: php, get, token

I am trying to grab a token from a link (that I had sent via email).

In the browser link, I can see the token:

```
https://myexample.com/newpassword.php?token=4aa6a0445da16849aec6757b0232f25c9e0fbfbb25a0d54a209be1b4a92c42e7af2f156050b92b0efaa1ca3d363819587700
```

However, when I use `$_GET["token"]` it is returning empty. Here is the code I used:

```php
  if(isset($_GET['token'])) {
    $token = trim($_GET['token']);
    echo $token;
    print_r($_GET);
  }
```

Both `print_r($_GET)` and `$token` are empty (although I can see the token in the browser link). Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Do `print_r($_SERVER)`. If you do not see `QUERY_STRING` no matter what you do, then it is most likely a server misconfiguration.

Comment: probably you are using the gmail which block the GET value and don't make send it to your php file. and you placed double semicolon on line 4

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. Greatly appreciate your help. I corrected the semicolon but another mistake I made was in placing the code after I did some processsing on some variables I got from a form on this page ... I placed the $_GET code right at the top of my php file and I was able to grab it. For some reason, once I do some validation checks on the variables, the token seems to disappear .. anyway it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell us anything about where the PHP is running - is it a hosted service? A machine you built yourself? Something else? What webserver (including version)? Nor did you tell us where your client is running (same machine? same LAN? remote?).

The first thing to check is in your server access logs - what request is arriving at your server? If the query string has been removed, you'll need to look at whatever is inbetween your client and the server. Then try...

```
<?php
print $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // this will tell you what the webserver is passing to PHP
```

From this you should be able to deduce if the problem is between your client and the webserver, between the webserver and PHP or within PHP itself.